# How to extend a Vue component with pug in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, pug, extend, nuxt.js

I understand Vue extending with pug; detailed here:
https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/06/11/vue-js-extending-components/

But in Nuxt, I can't find the way to `extend` or `include` the pug template into the child template. How to do that?

For example; this does not work because we don't have the `SurveyInputBase.pug` file in Nuxt, it is a component;

```
<template lang="pug">
  include SurveyInputBase.pug
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: [ 'question' ]
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to step up one level, and let webpack/vue-cli do the importing for you.  The pug plugin for vue is really only a rapid markup language tool and not the full dynamic page compilation package that pug/express is.

```
<template lang="pug">
  SurveyInputBase
</template>
<script>
  import SurveyInputBase from '@/components/SurveyInputBase';
  export default {
    components: [SurveyInputBase],
    props: [ 'question' ]
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did this but this time this does not "extend" actually. It looks like it only imports the base component like a pug file. Can we achieve this somehow as real "Base" component with template? SurveyInputBase's template and with methods etc?

Comment: Yes, read the vue.js component guide for more details on that.  It's using the regular vue.js syntax in this way.